# To display the spinner until all the data is rendered on the UI in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, data, spinner

```
<lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:chevrondown" variant="bare"
                                name="add-PickUpWindowSelect"
                                class="slds-m-left_xx-medium picklist-icon season-icon-edit"
                                onclick={toggleSelectDropInAddPickup}></lightning-button-icon>
                            <template if:true={showProductPicklistInEdit}>
                                <div style="width:100%;max-width:100%;" class="sids-list-view" role="listbox">
                                    <ul role="presentation" style="max-height:260px;overflow-y:auto;">
                                        <template if:true={showProductPicklistInEdit} for:each={productList}
                                            for:item="Product">
                                            <li role="presentation" key={Product.Id}>
                                                <div data-id={Product.Id} data-name={Product.Name}
                                                    onmouseover={subTypeHover} onclick={selectedProductFromPickList}
                                                    class="" role="option">
                                                    <span
                                                        style="padding-left: 0.5%; width: 55%">{Product.Name}</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </template>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </template>
```

When i click on the lightning button, the onclick function - `toggleSelectDropInAddPickup` sets the `toggleSelectDropInAddPickup` to true and each element in `productList` is rendered as the picklist values in the UI. `productList` is available in JS on load as a **Wire function**. But rendering he picklist values are taking a lot of time as there is a lot of data in `productList`. How do I add the spinner till all of the data in the `productList` is loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show the spinner with a promise.

```
async toggleSelectDropInAddPickup(event) {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.showProductPicklistInEdit = !this.showProductPicklistInEdit;
  await Promise.resolve(); // Waits one render cycle
  this.isLoading = false;
}
```

You then just need to show the spinner as appropriate:

```
<lightning-spinner if:true={isLoading}></lightning-spinner>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a private property `isLoading = true` so that when the LWC loads its default value is true

Set the value to false after all the `productList` data is loaded and processed by the wire function

Use lightning-spinner on the HTML to show the spinner while `isLoading` is true.

```
<lightning-spinner variant="brand" size="large" if:true={isLoading}> </lightning-spinner>
```

Comment: They did say the data is already loaded. They're trying to do rendering.